# Create dll that will print information about itself

Tags: c#, dll

Is it possible to create dll using C# that will display dll's name, date modified and file size? If is how to do so?

Comment: The answer is... yes.

Comment: @SonOfOmer you make use of the class `FileInfo`.

Comment: Oh, you only asked if it were possible, I didn't realize you actually wanted to accomplish the task as well as you don't seem to have tried at all.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me 100% with inputs that I had provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx.

**FileInfo class**

> provides properties and instance methods for the creation, copying,
>   deletion, moving, and opening of files, and aids in the creation of
>   FileStream objects. This class cannot be inherited.